# AWS Redshift Driver issues

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

We are using `AWS Redshift` Drivers to query our `Redshift` Database.Please find before the maven dependency for the driver which we use in our project.

```
com.amazon.redshift
redshift-jdbc41
1.2.1.1001
```

We are doing connection object pooling using

`org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource object.`

We have observed that even when we are closing the connections the connection seems to be active.The temp tables which should be dropped are not getting dropped. When different threads fetch different connection objects from the pool somehow they seem to behave as if they are same connections.The transactions started using these two different connection object seems to proceed together resulting is Serializable isolation violation exceptions. We are constantly running into such exceptions. I also wanted to know does Redshift support auto rollback if any query fails within a transaction,I am not able to see this behaviour.

Is there are any known issues in `AWS Redshift Drivers` or has any one else also faced similar problem